# Saving from for-if loopas numpty array or panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append, numpy-ndarray

I have datasets that have a length of 60 Minutes, I'm trying to add all of the data of the data files together in one pandas dataframe or a numpty-ndarray. In the end I want to use cumsum on the data.

However I'm stuck after the point where I append a dataset to an already existing empty file.

With a numpy-darray I get a numpy-ndarray with different numpy-ndarrays inside, instead of a single numpy-ndarray with all of the data.
In the Dataframe I only have the last set of data points saved.

```
ch1_total=[]
ch1_i=[]
df_ch1=pd.DataFrame(columns =['intensity'])

for filename, l in zip(filenames[:], L[:]):
    if ch1 :
       cont = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=ch1Start, max_rows=ch1N) # code programmed above not copied for this question
       t = cont [:, 0] + TimeOld
       c = cont[:, 1] \* ch1M + resetCh1
       data1=pd.DataFrame(c)
       data1.rolling(12).sum() / 12
       resetCh1 = c[-1]

       ch1_total.append(c) # original data as numpty array
    
       df1 = pd.concat([data1])
       #df_ch1.append(data1, ignore_index = True)
    
    df = pd.concat([df1], ignore_index=True)
    ch1_i.append(ch1_total)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: If you provide only one dataframe to `concat`, there is nothing it can concatenate the dataframe with.

Comment: numpy's `append` returns a new array with the appended data. It doesn't modify the existing array.